# Clean way to serialized/unserialized object with restkit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, restkit

I'm searching a way to manually serialized/unserialized object with restkit, I know how to serialize from an Object to a NSSTRING, but I don't how to unserialized from NSSTRING to Object.

Here is my code to serialized (I think it could be better...) :

```
     RKObjectSerializer* serializer = [RKObjectSerializer serializerWithObject:rr mapping:[[OMSRR apiMapping] inverseMapping]];

     NSError* error = nil;
     id<RKRequestSerializable> serialization = [serializer serializationForMIMEType:@"application/json" error:&error];

     NSString* sessionApiJsonified = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[serialization HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

How can I do the reversed way ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this (and why are you using RestKit to do it)?

Comment: I want to persist all my object in CoreData and retrieved them after, then to push them on an API and handle connections errors.

Comment: Ok, RestKit will be perfect for this. But that doesn't give you a reason to want to 'manually' serialise and deserialise. The whole point of RestKit is that you tell it the structure of the data returned from the API and how to put that data into CoreData and it deals the everything for you.

Comment: Yes I know, I'm developing a complex application that required customized handling of data. Do you know how to deserialized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RestKit 0.2**

To do what you're asking use [`RKMIMETypeSerialization`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKMIMETypeSerialization.html) ([`RKNSJSONSerialization`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKNSJSONSerialization.html)).

This isn't really what RestKit is designed for and you should try to use it at a higher level of abstraction. You want to use an instance of  [`RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectResponseMapperOperation.html). If you wanted to get NSObject instead of NSManagedObject you'd use [`RKObjectResponseMapperOperation`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectResponseMapperOperation.html).

**RestKit 0.10.3**

Easier to do in the old version of RestKit using[`RKManagedObjectMappingOperation`](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.3/Classes/RKManagedObjectMappingOperation.html).

Comment: do you have a way for previous version ? I realized Restkit 0.20 has removed OAuth2 protocol, I can't upgrade right now...